# Prepaid Sim at Frankfurt Airport

Tags: germany, europe, cellphones

Based on two answers to [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62342/sim-card-for-travelling-to-europe-from-india/64287) question, I intend to buy either lycamobile sim or Lebara sim. I found some very good options on https://www.lycamobile.de/en/

Following are the questions:

1. Can I buy either of the sims in India before I leave (e.g. at Mumbai Airport?). If yes, would they be overcharging as compared to buying in Germany?
2. If not, would these sims be available at Frankfurt Airport? On the website it says that sim is free and can be shipped within Germany for free. However, it would be great if the sim can be bought at airport, even if for small fee.
3. Once I get the sim card, how long does it take to activate the sim (asking this because in India it can take up to 24 hours) and do we need to submit some identity documents in hard copy somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've asked at least five questions in there.  It's well written, but be aware under the rules in the [help], the site works best when you have one main question per post.

Comment: @Mark sorry for the violation  I thought since they are all connected it would have be a mistake to separately all these similar questions. In anycase, will be more careful next time onwards.

Comment: Usually most big airports in Europe have a SIM vendor of some type and the registration is rather quick. Activation perioad is instant with exception of some cases and the price isn't that big. I would'nt advise to buy one from India before your trip.